# Own Custom Tags/Category page ( posts)

Tags: categories, customization, tags, page-template, template-tags

I want to make a page where on each **tags** :
My page should look alike : http://www.missmalini.com/aamir-khan-2/

Above page is coming from http://www.missmalini.com/celebrity-fan-pages/

this are categories with **Tags** :

I also know that the patten is like
Big Image is First ( **First** latest Post of resp. tag )... then 4 image with title are from **Second** post )and then only title after **sixth** post .. its means they have **divide latest 10-12 post** with this structure..

2 }  if u see on top ( above Ten Latest Aamir Khan Updates ) there is "**Aamir Khan Full Bio** " which is ***different*** for resp. **tags**.

3 } If Scroll Down there is **Photos and Videos** of resp. celeb ( which is tags or may be category wise )

Hence how i can do this ( means how i can make such Own Custom Page code ) can any one let me know.

Comment: any one here pls

Comment: At-least any one let me know logic how i can make such page

Comment: Hi, Any one here ?